# JavaScript: why use prototype to call a function instead of just calling the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, slice

Why would you slice an array like this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arr, 3);
```

Instead of simply:

```
arr.slice(3);
```

?

What are the benefits of using the prototype and the call?

Thanks!

Comment: 'arr' may not be an actual array. It could be a NodeList, or an arguments parameter, therefore the slice method isn't available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key benefits are realized when "arr" is not an array, but something *like* an array; specifically, something with a "length" property and numerically-keyed properties. Good examples are the `arguments` object and NodeList objects from a DOM. Those things won't have a "slice" method, but they *do* have numerically-keyed properties and a "length" property.

The trick works because the "slice" method is pretty forgiving.

If you see it being used with something that's definitely an array already, then you're looking at code written by a confused person :)

Oh, and note also that a short-cut is:

```
var foo = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

You don't have to go to the prototype directly if you don't want to; you can get at it from an array instance just as easily.  (Yes, it costs a dummy allocation, but in this day and age I wouldn't be surprised if VMs optimized that away.)

Comment: LOL.  Thanks!  That helps.  So, to make sure I understand:  Using the prototype/call method allows you to use prototype methods of objects on other objects that aren't of the given type?

Comment: @MrA yes - **but**: it only works if it works. In other words, that trick lets you get at a method and invoke it such that `this` is some object you've chosen. Will the method work?  Well, maybe, or maybe not. In this case, it does.

Comment: The methods that work on any object are documented in the specification as generic methods. You can directly copy a reference to them to avoid creating your own implementation. E.g. `List.prototype.add = Array.prototype.push`. or `NodeList.prototype.each = Array.prototype.forEach`